# Avoid NFC tag getting detected in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I have a requirement wherein my application deals with NFC.

I have declared NFC in the manifest file.

```xml
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>
```

My question is: Is it possible to disable the NFC tag detection in a specific activity?

For example, I have 10 activities and I don't want the 5th Activity to detect NFC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really stop the device from detecting NFC tags. What you can do, however, is to set your activity to receive (and then ignore) all NFC discovery events.

To do this, you would register your activity with the NFC foreground dispatch system using the NfcAdapter's [`enableForegroundDispatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29) method. This gives your current activity precedence in receiving NFC events over all other intent filters. See [Advanced NFC: Using the NFC Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) on how to do this registration.

Once you registered for the foreground dispatch system, your activity will receive all NFC intents in its `onNewIntent()` method (or as a pending intent result depending on how you register). There, you can simply ignore these events.

Comment: you save my day brother just disable the disableForegroundDispatch and every thing fine

Answer (score 0):

You just call simply this one  when your activity is destroy or pause

```
 nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(getActivity());
```